# How do I batch rename files in java?

Tags: java, powershell, batch-rename, renaming

I've got a list of files:

"f1.txt"
"f2.txt"
"f3.txt"
"f4.txt"

and want to batch rename to:

"file1.txt"
"file2.txt"
"file3.txt"
"file4.txt"

Ideally I would like to do this as a little java program but don't mind it being done in something like Windows PowerShell.

Thanks in advance

Lee

Comment: is that a java or a powershell question?

Answer (score 0):

Just buil a function that get two parametrs oldname,and newname and put it inside

```
 // File  with old name
        File file = new File("oldname");

        // File  with new name
        File file2 = new File("newname");
        if(file2.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

        // Rename file 
        boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
        if (!success) {

        }
    java.io.FileWriter out= new java.io.FileWriter(file2, true );//append=yes
```

Comment: You are using pre-JDK 7 code. A similar (and better) method already exists in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell, will rename all files in `$path`:

```
$path = "C:\pathToFiles"
cd $path
ls | % { Rename-Item $_.Name $_.Name.replace("f","file") }
```